# How to add elements to a list only if not already in list (from multiple datasets)

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working with multiple data sets of gene expression data (one data set per patient). I am trying to make a matrix that has all of the genes as each column, with expression data for each patient under the gene.

The problem is that some of the datasets have genes missing or not listed, so I do not necessarily have a reference for all of the genes.

So I am essentially trying to write a code that would record all of the genes in a dataset, and then only add additional genes to that list if it is not already present.

See example below:

I would like to make a list of unique genes from the two data sets:

```
Dataset 1                   Dataset 2
Gene     expression         Gene     expression
a        0.3                a        0.1
b        0.1                c        -0.3
e        0.2                d        0.05
f        0.2                f        -0.1


Ideal Output:
Genes = (a,b,c,d,e,f)

Instead I have been getting this output
Genes = (a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,)
```

When I attempt the code below, however, I get this warning message.
`In if (!(copynumber_df$gene %in% genes)) { ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Also, for some reason the output has every gene listed twice (so I end up with double from what I expected).

Why is each gene being added twice to the list?

```
copynumber_files <- list.files(data_dir) ###only 10 datasets/patients listed here 

genes <- c()


for (copynumber_file in copynumber_files){
  copynumber_df <- read.csv(copynumber_file, sep="\t")
  for (i in 1:nrow(copynumber_df)){
    if (copynumber_df$gene %in% genes == FALSE){
      genes <- append(genes, copynumber_df$gene)
    }
    else {}
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a basic example dataset so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: Do you want `!copynumber_df$gene[i] %in% genes` instead of `copynumber_df$gene %in% genes == FALSE`?

Comment: Why are you looping over each row separately? You are not using `i` inside the inner loop. Can you show how one file looks and what would be the output for it?

Comment: I have added a sample data set and ideal output. If possible, I'd also like to pair it with the expression data while leaving NA for any patient who does not have that gene listed.